Is it possible to biuld a random number generator that outputs 1 with probability $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$?
Suppose now you've already had a random generator $A$ that can output 1 with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$ with the exact value of $p$ unknown. Is it possible to use the generator $A$ to biuld a another random number generator $B$ that outputs $1$ with probability $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $0$ with probability $\displaystyle 1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$?
This problem comes from Introduction to Algorithms, Fourth edition with the original problem stated as follows. Suppose now you've already had a random generator $A$ that can output 1 with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$ with the exact value of $p$ unknown. Is it possible to use the generator $A$ to biuld a another random number generator $B'$ that outputs $1$ with probability $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$ and $0$ with probability $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$?
The solution is given as follows.
 while true
     random number x=A() // generating a random number from the random number generator A
     random number y=A() // generating another random number from the random number generator A
     if x != y
         return x

The feasibility of this algorithm is self-evident. In each iteration, the probabilities of $xy=01$ and $xy=10$ are both $p(1-p)$, which implies once the conditon $x\neq y$ is satisfied, $x$ has a $50\%$ chance of being $1$ and $50\%$ chance of being $0$.
Using the similar strategy, in fact we can build any generator that outputs $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $p$ as long as $p$ is a rational number. The way to do it is as follows. Let $\displaystyle p=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a\leq b$ and $a$, $b$ are positive integers.
 while true
     random number x[1]=A()
     random number x[2]=A()
     .
     .
     .
     random number x[b]=A()
     if (x[1]==1 and x[2]==0 and x[3]==0 and ... and x[b]==0) or
        (x[1]==0 and x[2]==1 and x[3]==0 and ... and x[b]==0) or
        (x[1]==0 and x[2]==0 and x[3]==1 and ... and x[b]==0) or
        ... or
        (x[1]==0 and x[2]==0 and x[3]==0 and ... and x[a]==1 and x_[a+1]==0 and ... and x[b]==0)
            return 1

However, I'm wondering whether it is possible to build a random number generator that can output 1 with probability $p$ where $p$ is irrational. For example, $\displaystyle p=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$? My personal understanding is that such random number generator is impossible to be built, but how to prove that? What's more, if it's impossible for $\displaystyle p=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, is it impossible for any irrational numbers? Any help will be appreciated.

I know how to define two different generators that suit what you need: let any $q\in (0,1)$ (for instance $q=\sqrt{2}/2$) and its binary expression $q=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\dots$.
Now start taking independent values $b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots$ of the generator you defined ($B'$), verifying that $b_i=1$ or $b_i=0$ with the same probability $1/2$. In the generators I will define, the probability that you need more than $n$ values of $b_i$ is $2^{-n}$.
First, define $X$ as follows: we get $b_i$ until the first $b_n$ such that $b_n\ne a_n$. Then we make $X=1$ if $b_n=0$ and $a_n=1$, but $X=0$ otherwise (i.e. $b_n=1$ and $a_n=0$). This is actually the same generator as in the answer by @lulu.
Alternatively, define $Y$ in this way: let $n$ the first index such that $b_n=1$, and take $Y=a_n$. The meaning of the binary expansion shows that the probability of being $Y=1$ equals $q$ as well.

You can build one that is $\frac 12$ for each, as $01$ and $10$ are equally probable.
Given that, you can output a uniformly random binary sequence, hence a uniformly random element in $[0,1]$.  Then, if your real number is $<\psi$ you can output $1$  and output $0$ otherwise.
Of course there is no a priori bound on how far you have to go in your binary sequence to determine whether or not it is $<\psi$.  For that matter, just producing a single $0$ or $1$ might take a lot of trials (if $p$ is near $0$ or $1$).

+1 This is in the spirit of arithmetic coding, BTW. "Of course there is no a priori bound on how far you have to go" But one can easily compute the expected number of trials.
